# Typo3 - record history weird behaviour

Tags: typo3, record, changelog

I am facing a weird problem which I've never seen before in typo3 version 6.0,
but right now I have to use typo3 4.5.29.
There's something wrong with the "record history", when I try to display change history of a page content, this is what I see:

[image: Record history weird behaviour]

Normally in the "Differences" column I would see the changes in green colored text and
the old values which were removed in red colored text, but I see some kind of number
which I don't even understand the meaning...

Anyone is facing the same thing ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Cindy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 uses external software called "diff" for creating a coloured view of the difference. Have a look at t3lib/class.t3lib_diff.php for implementation details.

I guess $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['diff_path'] is set wrong or diff is not available.

**untested:**

**If you cannot ask the admin of your server**, create an php-file somehow like this for testing purpose:

```
<?php 
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['diff_path'] = '/usr/bin/'; // do not know your system
$file1 = '';
$file2 = '';

$cmd = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['diff_path'] . '  ' . $file1 . ' ' . $file2;
$res = array();
echo exec($cmd, $res, $returnValue)
echo $res;
?>
```

This file should output something like

```
diff: missing operand
```

Comment: I just checked my conf :  $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['diff_path'] = diff, which I guess is fine but I'm not sure, and in t3lib/class.t3lib_diff.php, I don't quite know where to look at.

Comment: i added some test-code to my answer. "diff" seems not to be a Path!

Comment: thanks! I finally figured this out, thanks a lot, it worked with /usr/bin/diff